# Of five very similar Access reports, one groups by week differently

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, grouping

I have five similar Access front-end reports among several others.  These five all use Group on by week to group the report's records according to week ending Saturdays.  One report chooses to roll-up to Fridays instead; this is unacceptable.

The front-end pulls data from SQL Server back-end via pass-through queries/DSNless connections.  This works perfectly across the board.  All reports use one specific stored procedure that has several date fields but this one pulls in other date fields from an additional different database.  This one report uses that date field as the group on but it rolls-up to Fridays.  There is another date field pulled along and when I try to group on that one the report rolls up to Thursdays!  If I use any of the date fields from the stored procedure I can get the report to roll-up to Saturdays.  I have looked at the raw data that comes over in the ptq and the date fields all look formatted the same.  They date fields do have different dates in them for any given record and that is to be expected based on the differing ship date, delivered date, complete date, et al.  There seems to be something inherent in those two date fields associated with this specific report but at face value I cannot determine it.

I've copied the data to a table and created a new report whose recordsource is that table and both are in their own new little accdb though I seem to not be able to include it here.

As I try the different group-on date fields and their date field in the group on header, the report groups on Fridays or other inconsistent days of the week for the JobTenderDate and JobDeliveryDate but does group on Saturdays when MFG and REQDATE are used for group-on with its respective date in the associated group on header.  The other four reports that work use either MFG, REQDATE, or other date fields that let group on roll-up to Saturdays.  Why do those two date fields not allow Group on to roll-up to Saturday?

In the stored procedure all these date fields are SQL CAST AS DATE to strip out time stamps.  And in the SQL JOIN a COLLATE is required to get the data to be happy with each other.  Here's the FROM, JOIN, COLLATEs, and WHERE:

```
FROM
    dbo.vwRPUpdate_Rel Update_Rel
INNER JOIN 
    CompanyE.dbo.WipMaster wm
ON LEFT(wm.Job,6) = UPDATE_REL.JOB COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND SUBSTRING(wm.Job,7,1) = UPDATE_REL.REL COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE wm.Job LIKE '%A' AND wm.JobDeliveryDate BETWEEN @FromDate ANd @ToDate
```

Here's the table and data

```
Job JobTenderDate   JobDeliveryDate MFG REQDATE
RD83920A    2020-03-05  2020-03-06  2020-03-07  2020-03-07
RD83930A    2020-03-10  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
N432470A    2020-03-13  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
N432490A    2020-03-13  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
C139080A    2020-03-13  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
1836530A    2020-03-09  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
1901272A    2020-02-28  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
1902560A    2020-03-04  2020-03-27  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
1902422A    2020-03-13  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
1903130A    2020-03-10  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
1903450A    2020-03-11  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2000330A    2020-03-11  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2000570A    2020-03-02  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2070260A    2020-03-13  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2070270A    2020-03-13  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2031720A    2020-03-17  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
N433080A    2020-03-31  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
N433160A    2020-03-31  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
2090032A    2020-03-11  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
C139210A    2020-03-27  2020-04-03  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
C139330A    2020-04-01  2020-04-10  2020-04-04  2020-04-04
C139170A    2020-03-27  2020-04-10  2020-04-10  2020-04-10
C139190A    2020-03-27  2020-04-10  2020-04-10  2020-04-10
N432810A    2020-03-25  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2031850A    2020-03-27  2020-04-10  2020-04-10  2020-04-10
2031960A    2020-03-20  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2070090A    2020-01-24  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
C139090A    2020-03-24  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2000260A    2020-03-18  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2000060A    2020-03-17  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2030460A    2020-03-13  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2031340A    2020-03-18  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
2031380A    2020-03-27  2020-04-10  2020-04-10  2020-04-10
1937672A    2020-03-18  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
1901260A    2020-02-18  2020-04-10  2020-04-11  2020-04-11
1903040A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1902920A    2020-03-02  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1937981A    2020-03-25  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1935630A    2020-03-20  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1937200A    2020-03-20  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1930240A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1931611A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1931900A    2020-03-31  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1934102A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2031042A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2031160A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2000700A    2020-03-20  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2030211A    2020-03-13  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2000080A    2020-03-20  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1938941A    2020-03-03  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1938942A    2020-03-17  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
1938990A    2020-02-27  2020-04-17  2020-03-28  2020-03-28
C139110A    2020-03-20  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2031980A    2020-03-24  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2031550A    2020-03-25  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
C139150A    2020-03-25  2020-04-17  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
C139130A    2020-03-20  2020-04-20  2020-04-18  2020-04-18
2070280A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2030810A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2031760A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2031820A    2020-04-01  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
C139220A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1939060A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2000120A    2020-04-01  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1938320A    2020-03-17  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2000500A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-24  2020-04-24
2031210A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2031270A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-24  2020-04-24
2031520A    2020-03-26  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
2031540A    2020-03-31  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1934370A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1934850A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1931600A    2020-03-26  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1935710A    2020-03-18  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1936230A    2020-03-31  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1938183A    2020-03-02  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1937940A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1903160A    2020-03-31  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1903360A    2020-04-01  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1903371A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1903420A    2020-03-26  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1902392A    2020-04-01  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1901300A    2020-03-27  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1901172A    2020-03-25  2020-04-24  2020-04-25  2020-04-25
1902220A    2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
1902980A    2020-03-25  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
1937950A    2020-03-17  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
1932680A    2020-03-27  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
1934893A    2020-03-25  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2031440A    2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030212A    2020-03-20  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030213A    2020-03-27  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030240A    2020-03-25  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030140A    2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030180A    2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030640A    2020-03-18  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2000590A    2020-04-01  2020-05-01  2020-05-02  2020-05-02
2030430A    2020-03-20  2020-05-08  2020-05-09  2020-05-09
1938184A    2020-03-02  2020-05-08  2020-05-09  2020-05-09
1937600A    2020-03-26  2020-05-08  2020-05-09  2020-05-09
2070240A    2020-03-02  2020-05-08  2020-05-09  2020-05-09
2000040A    2020-04-01  2020-05-15  2020-05-16  2020-05-16
2000090A    2020-03-26  2020-05-22  2020-05-23  2020-05-23
2000100A    2020-03-26  2020-05-22  2020-05-23  2020-05-23
2032050A    2020-03-31  2020-05-22  2020-05-23  2020-05-23
2070230A    2020-02-25  2020-06-12  2020-06-13  2020-06-13
1901273A    2020-03-17  2020-06-26  2020-06-27  2020-06-27
1970440A    2019-07-02  2020-12-12  2020-12-12  2020-12-12
N430250A    2019-12-04  2020-12-26  2020-12-31  2020-12-31
```

[image: New table shows Date/Time field type]

The new table verifies correct field type coming over.

[image: Access Group, Sort, and Total section]
All the reports Group on by week.  There are no other options to adjust for the by-week setting.

Where would I apply the datepart("ww",[JobTenderDate]) code?

As I look at the dates in the four date fields, I see the MFG and REQDATE are all mostly Saturday dates to begin with with a few, Friday dates.  When sorted on REQDATE, all the 4/10 dates roll-up to the Friday 4/10 even though there are more 4/11 dates.  I am not understanding how group-on is determining which date to roll-up to.  And when I look at JobDeliveryDate, its dates are mostly the preceding Friday and FobTenderDate is all over the place and mostly do not coincide with Saturday roll-up dates.  Is this where the code you suggest would come into play?  I still don't understand where exactly it would be placed.  Or is there some information out here that can expound on Access' Group on defining characteristics?

OK, so the report is doing what it is told with the dates it is given, depending on which date field is used.  How can I force all group-ons to always roll-up to Saturdays and contain the dates from the week leading to that Saturday?

TIA,
Tim

Comment: If the columns are FOR SURE coming back as date values for Access? (a easy test is to fire up query builder - create a append  on a pass-though query that calls the store proc with the dates). Now flip that local table into design view - double check the data types.  If all is well? Then I would look at what expression you are using for the group by. Perhaps you have week which returns the week day 1-7 (starting on sunday). You might need/want datepart("ww",[JobTenderDate]) to get the calendar week (1-52)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - Where does datepart("ww".[JobTenderDate]) get used?  In a query between the ptq and report?  In the report filter?

Comment: Depends on what grouping you want  in the report  - it comes down to how you are doing the grouping. if you group by weekday[somedate] then it will group by day of week (1-7 - starting with 1 = Sunday). Such a grouping would not be of much use, since say all Mondays for the last year would be grouped on the number 2 (2 = monday). So if you want to group by the week of the year, then you can group by DatePart("ww",[somedate]). You can group by this result in the report, or add the column to the query. But, again, the 9th week of 2020 and say 2019 would be included if that's your date range.

Comment: I mean, how were and are you grouping the week now? You likely want to include the year as part of the expression if the date range passes over a year (since now weeks from the two years would be grouped in the same week). So how you do this is really up to you but you must have been grouping on some kind of expression now - hence your question.  I think most easy would be to add a column that spits out the week, and perhaps another column that spits out year. So your report would group by year, and then group by week.  I mean, what expression are you using now?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I am solely using the report's Group on - by week.  I am doing no grouping in the sp or in a query in between the ptq and report.  IN the sp I am only pulling between two date parameters.

Comment: So, ok - you are grouping by week (using report). That should spit out a number 1-52. Only issue to watch for is if year is different . To start the date on Saturday, then you can use this in the query: datepart("ww",date(),vbSaturday)). However, you might as well add this column to the t-sql query. You can use DATEPART(wk, [JobTenderDate]) as JobWeek. Run that query - take a look at the column result. You could also use a query (client side - access) against the PT query you have to add these colums, but might as well spit them out t-sql side.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the one computer has some different date settings.

Try forcing a specific rule for obtaining a week number having Sunday as the first day of the week:

```
DatePart("ww",[JobTenderDate],1)
```